# O(1) deletion in an unordered vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl

In a C++ program I have a collection of plain-old-data for which I need be able to efficiently:

- Add elements.
- Iterate over the whole collection.
- Remove some of those elements (see update below).iteration, see below).

I do not have to use a set or map type because there is no *external* requirement for:

- Indexing into it
- Maintaining ordering.
- Efficiently finding elements or test for them being in the collection.

If I had to write it from scratch in C, I would use an exponentially growing dynamic array and the deletion operation would move the last element into the freed-up slot.  That way deletion is O(1).

If I want to use a C++ standard container it seems I could (a) use a `std::vector` but write the deletion operation by hand or (b) use an `std::list`.  I have a mild, but definite, dislike of linked lists.

Both solutions are acceptable to me, but I would really rather have it both ways: to use a vector but using only standard operations.  Is there a way to do this.

**Update:**

The comments below made clear that I am not looking for a general deletion operation.  My problem requires me to iterate over the collection frequently and on each pass I expect to discover that some elements have to be removed.

I can do that whole operation in O(n) time regardless of the number of deletions.  But this is obviously a bespoke operation and I should have known I need to write my own loop.  Surprisingly though `remove_if` *almost* solves my problem.  If the only thing I needed to do in the iteration pass was identify the out-of-date elements, then `remove_if` would do the job, but I need to do other processing too.

Comment: if you need to **Remove elements** ==> you need to **Efficiently find elements or test for them being in the collection**

Comment: @karim It could be done inefficiently...

Comment: Sounds like you might want a [`std::multiset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset) this allows fast insertion and removal, plus O(logN) lookup for finding elements.

Comment: What @karim says is very important! While erasing and insertion in the middle of an `std::vector` is O(n) as opposed to the O(1) for e.g. a list, the constant for the O(n) iteration over the collection is so much smaller for the contiguous `std::vector` that it will make the cost for removing and insertion insignificant for *all* big n. You should at the very least try `std::vector`, it most likely is your fastest option.

Comment: I'd be inclined to use a `std::vector` and build a special function for the removal (that uses `std::move`).

Comment: It depends how large the collection is, the size of each element, etc.   Depending on size and performance of bog standard vector, you could just create a new vector doing a single pass of the old one and pushing only items that don't match.  That's (edit:) O(N).

Comment: @karim if, while I am iterating over the array I find that I want to remove an element, then I have found it.   Thus, even though the find operation is O(n), nothing is lost to me.

Comment: @AdrianRatnapala yes, sure but you said that you need to efficiently remove element, and to efficiently remove an element, you must efficiently find that element, O(n) is not that efficient, so i suggest you to use a hash table to have O(1) add/remove/find element. but if O(n) is acceptable for you, then you can use a linked list or dynamic array .

Comment: @karim It's not that O(n) is acceptable to me for deletion.  It is that I have to iterate over the thing anyway, see the update above.

Comment: @AdrianRatnapala Hash table have O(1) for insert/delete/find operation if well implemented. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, this is all already in the standard library:

- Store your data in an [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)
- Remove data with [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) followed by [`std::vector::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) which can then act on the very end of the vector (see [Erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom)). Alternatively, you can have a look at [boost::remove_erase_if](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/new/remove_erase_if.html), although I do not know whether this unnecessarily preserves order or not. But at least it is O(n) in the end.
- Add data with [`std::vector::push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) (or [`std::vector::insert(end)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) to efficiently insert a whole range)

The `std::remove_if` also lets you remove a whole bunch of elements in a single iteration.

And, probably most importantly, iteration will be maximally fast due to your data being stores contiguously -> No cache misses.

Comment: Thanks this looks like what I want but before I accept the answer I need to read more carefully and check that `remove_if` does what I think it does.  I have already upvoted you because `remove_if` is an interesting find in any case.

Comment: @AdrianRatnapala Actually, now that I reread the documentation, it apparently does not what you want: *"Removing is done by shifting (by means of move assignment) the elements in the range in such a way that the elements that are not to be removed appear in the beginning of the range. Relative order of the elements that remain is preserved"* So if this performance matters, you might need to look for something else.

Comment: @AdrianRatnapala I added an alternative I found. It has the right overall complexity at least. Anyway, hand crafting such a modified `remove_if` for bidirectional iterators should not be to hard if actually needed.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I will be writing my own loop, but it turns of  `remove_if` is an answer to this type of question.  As I say in the update above, I need to write my own loop because I will be doing things other than just evaluating the predicate.

Comment: I don't think there would be a performance problem.   `remove_if` will remove all elements satisfying the predicate in O(n) time, which is all I could hope for.  The boost extension seems to merely add the erase that you will need afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an erase function which moves an element from the end of container:

```
template <typename Vector>
void unordered_erase(Vector& v, typename Vector::iterator it) {
    *it = std::move(v.back());    
    v.pop_back();
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aaf9bc36f3405d81)

Answer (score 0):

You could write a wrapper for the `delete` function in a vector wherein you copy the last element into the position to be deleted, and then you call the standard `erase` function at the last element. Erasing the last element would be O(1).

It would go something like this:

```
void delete(vector<int> data, int position)
{
  data[position] = data[data.size() - 1];
  data.erase(data.begin() + data.size() - 1);
  return;
}
```

I'm assuming that to delete a number, you give the position from which it is to be deleted. If it is something else, please specify.

Comment: The OP says that he doesn't need to maintain ordering, so an index is unlikely to be useful here

Comment: Since the OP cites efficiency, reworking this so a value copy is not taken would be no bad thing. I know they mention POD but would be worth it anyway for future.

Comment: An index could be very useful depending on how often and what operations he wants to perform.  For example if I want to remove all 2's in a huge collection very quickly but wasn't fussed about how long it took to create the collection or how long it takes to iterate over it, I could store them in an unordered_map keyed on number.  But I remember Stroustroup saying vector almost always performs better given the characteristics of modern CPUs. https://isocpp.org/blog/2014/06/stroustrup-lists

Answer (score 0):

It depends how large the collection is, the size of each element, etc. Depending on size and performance of bog standard vector, you could just create a new vector doing a single pass of the old one and pushing only items that don't match. That's O(N).

The Standard Library has std::copy_if.  For example, the following removes all value 2 from the first vector.  What's left is in the second.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main(void)
{
    std::vector<int> v1 = { 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2, 3, 2, 2};
    std::vector<int> v2;

    std::copy_if(v1.begin(), v1.end(), std::back_inserter(v2), [](int value) { 
        return value != 2;
    });

}
```

In my performance test (with 50,000,000 random numbers), this is slightly slower than the remove_if method however:

Release 32: copy_if (1412), remove_if (1120)

Release 64: copy_if (1420), remove_if (1141)

Comment: You should probably reserve enough space in `v2`. That will not lead to a huge speedup, but might be significant here.

Comment: It is kind of.  With reserve copy_if 64 goes down to 1256, still slower than remove_if but less so.  Though as you don't know how many X's there are in the collection, you have to reserve the same number as the original array from the start.  If you don't reserve it's slower but your final array size is optimal.

Comment: Yeah, obviously depends on whether memory is a bottleneck or not. In the stuff I do, it usually is not.

Comment: Btw, if we are sure we are dealing with POD, we can even resize `v2` beforehand and then erase the space we did not need (or, for better reusability, just safe the last index). That would get rid of the `back_inserter` which has some overhead to afaik, but at the cost of needlessly zeroing the data once beforehand. Might especially be useful if we can reuse our target buffer.  But no idea if this has a noticeable effect. And as you can see, this is getting ugly. :)

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to your whole problem:

```
std::vector<MyClass> v;
// ...fill v...
v.erase(std::partition(v.begin(), v.end(), [](MyClass& element) -> bool {
    // ...process element and return false if element should be deleted.
}), v.end());
```

I know it's late but someone might still find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative to remove_if that does the swap back without maintaining order.

```
/// faster remove_if, but it doesn't keep order.
/// Swaps matched items to back; returns iterator to start of matched items
template <typename C, typename F>
inline typename C::iterator swapBackIf(C & v, F comp) {
  auto iter = v.begin();
  auto rear = v.end();
  for (iter; iter < rear; ++iter) {
    auto const& ele = *iter;
    if (comp(ele)) {
      std::iter_swap(iter, --rear);
    }
  }
  return rear;
}
```